# authpuppy "The node you're trying to access does not exist on the server"

Tags: authentication, captiveportal

somebody can help me, how configure wifidog gateway to authpuppy, coz when user connect always notif error "The node you're trying to access does not exist on the server"

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a node so that when request goes to **authpuppy** it can refer you to a specific node i.e the configured router.

Steps to Create a Node

1. Manage Nodes
2. Create Node
3. Name the node exactly what you named the **Gateway Id** when you
   configured Router in **wifidog.conf** file
4. save it

Then Connect to wifi Your problem be solved